# Placing content children inside component's subcomponent

Tags: angular

I have the following:

Component.html

```
<container-component>
    <item-component *ngFor="let item of contentItems">
        <! -- render content child here -->
    </item-component>     
</container-component>
```

Component.ts

```
...
selector: 'component'
...
@ContentChildren(ItemComponent) contentItems: QueryList<ItemComponent>;
```

ItemComponent.ts

```
...
selector: 'item-component'
...
```

Usage:

```
<component>
    <content></content>
</component>
```

I have a component that should dynamically generate wrap content children (`<content>`) inside its `item-component`s).

I tried making the `item-component`s a `ViewChildrenRef` of `ItemComponent`s and placing each of the `contentItems` in as a `View` using `createEmbeddedRef`. That didn't work since Angular doesn't recognize `contentItems` as `TemplateRef`s.

How would I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by getting an instance of `<content>`'s `TemplateRef` using a template reference variable for all of `<content>`'s template and then using that in `Component`'s template in a `<ng-template>`:

Component.html

```
<container-component>
    <item-component *ngFor="let item of contentItems">
        <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="item.templateRef"></ng-template>
    </item-component>     
</container-component>
```

Content.ts

```
...
@ViewChild('itemTemplate') itemTemplate;
...
```

Content.html

```
<ng-container #itemTemplate>
    <!-- content stuff -->
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass contentItems from container-component to item-component:

```
<item-component [items]="contentItems">
```

And then in item-component ts accept it:

```
@Input() items;
```

And in template put:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <! -- render content child here -->
</ng-container>
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I probably should have mentioned but I can't change the interface of `<item-component>`. Its template is only made up of `<ng-content></ng-content>`.